# filter on nested entries and grouping header

Tags: angularjs

If have the following setup so far.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div id="personList" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <div class="gwsSearchItemInput" >Suchen: <input ng-model="searchText" /></div>
            <a name="top"></a>
            <div style="display: inline;" ng-repeat='group in getGroups()'>
                <h2 style="display: inline;"><a href="#letter{{group}}">{{group}}</a></h2>
            </div>
            <div ng-repeat='group in getGroups()'>
                <h2><a name="letter{{group}}">{{group}}</a></h2>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="person in persons | groupby:group | orderBy: 'DisplayName' | filter:searchText" class="employeebox">
                        <p>{{ person.DisplayName }}</p>
                        <p>{{ person.department }}</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#top">top</a>
            </div>      
    </div>          
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
console.log("hello");
myApp.filter('groupby', function () {
    return function (items, group) {
        return items.filter(function (element, index, array) {
            return element.GroupByFieldName == group;
        });
    }
})

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.persons = [{
        'GroupByFieldName': 'M',
        'DisplayName': 'Meier, Hans',
        'department': 'Department 1'
    }, {
        'GroupByFieldName': 'S',
        'DisplayName': 'Schmidt, Thomas',
        'department': 'Department 1'
    }, {
        'GroupByFieldName': 'S',
        'DisplayName': 'Smith, John',
        'department': 'Department 2'
    }, {
        'GroupByFieldName': 'J',
        'DisplayName': 'Johnson, Steve',
        'department': 'Department 1'
    }];

    $scope.getGroups = function () {
        var groupArray = [];
        //filter = $filter('searchText');
        //console.log("filter: " + $filter.searchText);
        //$scope.persons = $filter('filter')($scope.persons, {DisplayName:$filter.searchText});
        angular.forEach($scope.persons, function (item, idx) {
            if (groupArray.indexOf(item.GroupByFieldName) == -1)
                groupArray.push(item.GroupByFieldName)
        });
        return groupArray.sort();
    }
}]);
```

[http://plnkr.co/edit/N26eopH210mTgA1nzGn8](http://plnkr.co/edit/N26eopH210mTgA1nzGn8?p=preview)

I would like to be able to filter e.g. 'Meier' and see only the group 'M' afterwards. Now only the persons inside the groups are affected by the filter.
Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You probably want to apply the `filter:searchText` inside the `getGroups()` method.

Comment: Sounds like it would like to do that. Unfortunately I do not know how nor do I find any good documentation/example for this.

Comment: I think [on hold] can be removed due to the fact the Maxim edited the question and added the code example. @Stewie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you don't do anything but change a bit your `getGroups` method.

```
$scope.searchText = '';

$scope.getGroups = function () {
        var groupArray = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.persons, function (item, idx) {
            if (groupArray.indexOf(item.GroupByFieldName) == -1 &&
                item.DisplayName.indexOf($scope.searchText) !== -1)
                groupArray.push(item.GroupByFieldName)
        });
        return groupArray.sort();
    }
```

on any text we type, we change output of `getGroups()`

Demo <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/U80t4bAZw1XXCaaoa0hO?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: That is the way I was for looking for. I've just changed `item.DisplayName.indexOf($scope.searchText) !== -1)` to `item.DisplayName.toUpperCase().indexOf($scope.searchText.toUpperCase()) !== -1)` so that the user has not to think about capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it has the same behavior as you wish, but you can do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat='group in getGroups()'>
  <div class="wrapper" data-ng-show="!searchText || searchText.charAt(0) == group">
    <h2><a name="letter{{group}}">{{group}}</a></h2>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="person in persons | groupby:group | orderBy: 'DisplayName' | filter:searchText" class="employeebox">
        <p>{{ person.DisplayName }}</p>
        <p>{{ person.department }}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#top">top</a>
</div>
```

That way, you show the group only when: or no filter at all are being applying, or the first char of the filter is the same as the group letter.

Comment: Close but not 100% what I'm looking for because if you filter for 'Hans' in my example who is a part of group 'M' you do not see because char 'H' does not match group 'M'.